# ASCII Character in URL causing encoding debug warning in Scrapy

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, scrapy, web-crawler

Below, I have a rather straight-forward 1-layer crawler for Scrapy to execute.
It accesses the search results on the Leis Municipais database for a 2 year (2012-2014) period for the city of São Paulo. **Note, that the start URL contains ASCII formatted characters**

Most of the time, for instance when an ASCII space is included in a URL (%20), I simply use the "u" piece of code next to the quoted string to encode in unicode, and this works (i.e., there are no problems in crawling or parsing).

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from lei_municipal.items import LeiMunicipalItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "leis"
    allowed_domains = ["leismunicipais.com.br"]
    start_urls = [u"https://www.leismunicipais.com.br/cgi-local/forpgs/topsearch.pl?city=S%E3o%20Paulo&state=SP&tp=ord&page_this=1&block=0&year1=2012&year2=2014&ementaouintegra=naementa&wordkey=&&camara=1"]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="pages_ant_prox"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        leis = hxs.select('//div[@id="law_text"]')
        items = []
        for leis in leis:
            item = LeiMunicipalItem()
            item ["numero"] = leis.select("a/b/text()").extract()[0].encode("utf-8")
            item ["descricao"] = leis.select("a/div/text()").extract()[0].encode("utf-8")
            item ["url"] = leis.select("a/@href").extract()[0].encode("utf-8")
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

When I execute the above code I get the following DEBUG warnings:

> 2014-07-03 17:15:01-0300 [leis] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to
>   https://www.leismunicipais.com.br> from https://www.leismunicipais.com.br/cgi-local/forpgs/topsearch.pl?block=10&camara=1&city=S%C3%A3o+Paulo&ementaouintegra=naementa&page_this=2&state=SP&tp=ord&wordkey=&year1=2012&year2=2014>
>   2014-07-03 17:15:01-0300 [leis] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to
>   https://www.leismunicipais.com.br> from https://www.leismunicipais.com.br/cgi-local/forpgs/topsearch.pl?block=490&camara=1&city=S%C3%A3o+Paulo&ementaouintegra=naementa&page_this=50&state=SP&tp=ord&wordkey=&year1=2012&year2=2014> 2014-07-03 17:15:02-0300 [leis] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.leismunicipais.com.br> (referer:
>   https://www.leismunicipais.com.br/cgi-local/forpgs/topsearch.pl?city=S%E3o%20Paulo&state=SP&tp=ord&page_this=1&block=0&year1=2012&year2=2014&ementaouintegra=naementa&wordkey=&&camara=1)
>   2014-07-03 17:15:02-0300 [leis] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

***The first suggestion has been to test the xpaths***:

From the scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.leismunicipais.com.br/cgi-local/forpgs/topsearch.pl?city=S%E3o%20Paulo&state=SP&tp=ord&page_this=1&block=0&year1=2012&year2=2014&ementaouintegra=naementa&wordkey=&&camara=1"
```

Testing the first selector:

```
hxs.select('//a[@class="pages_ant_prox"]/text()')
```

Yields:

> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//a[@class="pages_ant_prox"]' data=u'a
> >     href="topsearch.pl?city=S%C3%A3o%20Pa'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector
> >     xpath='//a[@class="pages_ant_prox"]' data=u'a
> >     href="topsearch.pl?city=S%C3%A3o%20Pa'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector
> >     xpath='//a[@class="pages_ant_prox"]' data=u'a
> >     href="topsearch.pl?city=S%C3%A3o%20Pa'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector
> >     xpath='//a[@class="pages_ant_prox"]' data=u'a
> >     href="topsearch.pl?city=S%C3%A3o%20Pa'

Testing one of the second set of selectors:

```
hxs.select('//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()')
```

Yields:

> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16010/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16009/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16008/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16007/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16006/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16005/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16004/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16003/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16002/2014'
> >
> > HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//div[@id="law_text"]/a/b/text()' data=u'LEI ORDIN\xc1RIA N\xba: 16001/2014'

**My question is**: Why is the start URL not being encoded properly and thus scrapy is not crawling and parsing the desired information? How can this be corrected? From my own personal trouble-shooting the problem appears to be specific to the "%e3" character (~ the ã in São Paulo).

After testing the selectors in the shell, I am even more confused as to why the current script is not parsing/displaying the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the url problem. The site does a meta refresh, meaning they probably have an anticrawl mechanism of sorts.

Comment: Can you provide any links to information on how to counter-act said meta refresh mechanisms?

*** I probably should have mentioned in my question above that I am a Scrapy newbie here!

Comment: I took a better look at the site. It doesn't have an anticrawl mechanism (yay!). I'd re-check the xpaths for both the link extractor and the content extractor. The site is a bit poorly designed, for instance it has a same id for all the law containers.